# I cannot delete files to Recycle Bin

Tags: delphi

I cannot delete files to Recycle Bin.

```
VAR SHFileOpStruct: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin   
  with SHFileOpStruct  do
  begin
    wnd   := Handle; 
    wFunc := FO_DELETE;
    pFrom := PChar(FileName);
    fFlags:= 0;
    pTo   := NIL;
    hNameMappings:= NIL;
    lpszProgressTitle:= NIL;
  end;
  Result:= SHFileOperation(SHFileOpStruct); 
end;
```

I can delete files in this format: '1.xyz' but not in this format '12.xyz' (file name is longer than 1 character).

Comment: How are you handling the memory allocation of pFrom? Seems like that might be your problem. The memory location can only hold up to 1.xyz and doesn't fit 12.xyz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation of SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should not use GetLastError to see if the operation succeeds. Check the Result of the function and use the documentation to figure out the error it returns. That should give you a better clue what the problem is.

EDIT:

Best guess from reading the documentation:

> pFrom
>
> Although this member is declared as a
>   single null-terminated string, it is
>   actually a buffer that can hold
>   multiple null-delimited file names.
>   Each file name is terminated by a
>   single NULL character. The last file
>   name is terminated with a double NULL
>   character ("\0\0") to indicate the end
>   of the buffer

So you should make sure pFrom is ended with a double 0. Try the following

```
pFrom := PChar(FileName + #0);
```

Also, what Delphi version are you using?

EDIT2:

Also make sure the structure is properly initialized to 0. Uncomment the FillChar

Comment: The result of the function is 2 or 87 (57hex).

Comment: There is also this hint in documentation, but I don't understand it exactly: "This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by IFileOperation". Does it mean that there is an optional alternative function or that that SHFileOperation was totally replaced and it should not be used anymore under Vista?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
function DeleteToRecycleBin(WindowHandle: HWND; Filename: string; Confirm: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  SH: TSHFILEOPSTRUCT;
begin
  FillChar(SH, SizeOf(SH), 0);
  with SH do
  begin
    Wnd := WindowHandle;
    wFunc := FO_DELETE;
    pFrom := PChar(Filename + #0);
    fFlags := FOF_SILENT or FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
    if not Confirm then
    begin
      fFlags := fFlags or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
    end;
  end;
  Result := SHFileOperation(SH) = 0;
end;
```

Comment: What Window Handle is expected for the parameter WindowHandle? What if this is being used with {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}?

Comment: @tim11g in that case Wnd := 0;

Answer (score -1):

You may want to set the fFlags := FOF_SILENT + FOF_ALLOWUNDO + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION